# How would I convert regular expression to finite automata?

Tags: regex, finite-automata, regular-language

How would I change the following regular expression to finite automata?

```
(abUb)(bUaaa)b*b((a*b)*Ub)*
```

note: U means union in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are five top-level concatenated components of this regex. According to the algorithm recoverable from a part of Kleene's theorem, you can make NFA-Lambdas for these, then form the concatenation by connecting final states of one to initial states of the next.

When you see a union, that means you make two machines and combine them by making a new start state with two lambda transitions.

Kleene closure is a little more involved, but basically make the machine for the thing being repeated, then transform it by adding a new accepting start state and a loop to it from the old final states.

The base case is the machine for a single letter, which is two states, initial and final, with the appropriately labelled transition.

Work recursively from the simplest machines (innermost subexpressions) up to the whole thing, combining as necessary. Simplify the result as much as you like, possibly converting to a minimal DFA.

Comment: ok so far im good with everything up to: ((a*b)*Ub)*. Once I get there I dont know what to do

Comment: The outermost operation is \*. So first, built a machine for (a*b)* U b. The outermost operation here is U, so build two machines: one for (a*b)* and one for b. The machine for b is trivial. For the other, the outermost operation is \*, so build a machine for a*b. The outermost operation is concatenation, so build machines for a* and b. The machine for b is trivial. The outermost operation for the other is \*, so build a machine for a; this is trivial. Now, go back up the recursion stack and apply the appropriate rules to form Kleene closures, concatenations and unions.

Comment: when you say its trivial, do you mean we stop building on to it?

Comment: @tehman: have you read the proof of Kleene's theorem? It gives an algorithm for converting finite automata into regular expressions and conversely. If you read it, you will discover what Patrick87 means by "trivial."

Answer (score 0):

There is an application called Automatic Java Code Generator for Regular Expressions and Finite Automata, that automatically generates the NFA, DFA (including the transition table), and Java Code for a given regular expression or finite automata. It can be downloaded from this link: [www.s-solutions.info](http://www.s-solutions.info) You can always check if your solution is correct or not.